# How to change Hole Table axis orientation via SolidWorks API?

Tags: vba, solidworks

Is there a way to change **orientation (direction) of Hole Table axes** with SolidWorks API?

I can do it manually by dragging the handles but recorded VBA macro does not contain actual changes.

This is what I would like to achieve:

Before
[image: before]

After
[image]

I don't have Visual Studio Tools on this PC so I cannot record a C# or VB macro and see if it contains more code. If somebody could check that on their PC I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. This time digging through SolidWorks API Help was useful.

By using `HoleTable.DatumOrigin.SetAxisPoints()` method it is possible to change points that define the Hole Table axes.
Important to notice is that `SetAxisPoints()` changes **only the end points** of the axis arrows (tips of the arrowheads). Start points get updated automatically.

You can get current point values with `HoleTable.DatumOrigin.GetAxisPoints2()` method.

Another thing to notice is that values in the hole table do not get updated automatically. They did update after I manually dragged a an axis point.
To get them update by the code set `HoleTable.EnableUpdate` property to `False` before and back to `True` after the call to `SetAxisPoints()`.

Here is the code excerpt that does what I needed:

```
Dim ht As SldWorks.HoleTable
Dim htdo As SldWorks.DatumOrigin
Dim htdaxpts() As Double
Dim htdaxptsnew(0 To 3) As Double
Dim ystarty As Double
Dim yendx As Double
Dim yendy As Double
Dim xstartx As Double
Dim xendx As Double
Dim xendy As Double

    '...
    'here comes code to prepare for Hole Table insertion
    '...

    'insert the Hole Table
    Set htann = theView.InsertHoleTable2(False, anchorx, anchory, swBOMConfigurationAnchor_BottomLeft, "A", holetemplatepath)

    If Not htann Is Nothing Then
        Set ht = htann.HoleTable
        Set htdo = ht.DatumOrigin

        'disable hole table update to get it refresh when done
        ht.EnableUpdate = False

        'get coordinates of the axis arrows (4 pairs of (x,y) doubles: X start(0,1), X end(2,3), Y start(4,5), Y end(6,7))
        htdaxpts = htdo.GetAxisPoints2()
        'take the values we use
        xstartx = htdaxpts(0)
        xendx = htdaxpts(2)
        xendy = htdaxpts(3)
        ystarty = htdaxpts(5)
        yendx = htdaxpts(6)
        yendy = htdaxpts(7)
        'change direction only if Y arrow points up
        If ystarty < yendy Then
            yendy = ystarty - (yendy - ystarty)
        End If
        'change direction only if X arrow points left
        If xstartx > xendx Then
            xendx = xstartx - (xendx - xstartx)
        End If
        'change position only if X arrow is below Y arrow
        If xendy < ystarty Then
            'we can change end point only so change X end y only
            xendy = xendy + (ystarty - xendy) * 2
        End If
        'prepare new axis points (2 pairs of (x,y) doubles: X end(0,1), Y end(2,3))
        htdaxptsnew(0) = xendx
        htdaxptsnew(1) = xendy
        htdaxptsnew(2) = yendx
        htdaxptsnew(3) = yendy
        'set new axis end points
        htdo.SetAxisPoints htdaxptsnew

        'enable hole table update to refresh the values
        ht.EnableUpdate = True

    End If
```